# Using IBufferConstruction to create single and multiple buffers (VBA and ArcObjects)

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-9.3, vba

I need a bit of help with using the iBufferContruction interface, my overall goal is that the user clicks on the map, a graphic is created and then buffered,at multiple distances and then stored in a featureclass

So far, i can create a single buffer (i know if it created because the length that gets returned is correct), however when I store it in my FC the shape is empty.

Here's the code:

```
Private Sub Buffer_MouseDown(ByVal button As Long, ByVal shift As Long, ByVal x As Long, ByVal y As Long)

'Get the location of the mouse and set it to the point
Set m_pPoint = m_pMxDoc.ActiveView.ScreenDisplay.DisplayTransformation.ToMapPoint(x, y)

'new marker element on the map
Set m_pElement = New MarkerElement

'set the element property
m_pElement.Geometry = m_pPoint

Set m_pGraphics = m_pMap

m_pGraphics.AddElement m_pElement, 0 'Grpahic for the point click.

Set m_pAC = m_pMxDoc.ActiveView

'refresh the map
m_pAC.PartialRefresh esriViewGraphics, Nothing, Nothing
'
Dim pPoly As IPolygon4
Set pPoly = New Polygon

'Dim pPoly As IPolygonElement
'Set pPoly = New PolygonElement

Dim pBC As IBufferConstruction
Set pBC = New BufferConstruction

'Dim pBCProp As IBufferConstructionProperties
'Set pBCProp = pBC
'pBCProp.ExplodeBuffers = True

Set pPoly = pBC.Buffer(m_pElement.Geometry, 200)
Debug.Print pPoly.Length ' RETURNS 1256.63706143592

'pBC.ConstructBuffers
Dim pFeat As IFeature
Dim pfeatureCursor As IFeatureCursor
Dim pfeatureBuffer As IFeatureBuffer

Set pfeatureBuffer = m_pBufferFClass.CreateFeatureBuffer
Set pfeatureCursor = m_pBufferFClass.Insert(True)
Set pFeat = pfeatureBuffer

pfeatureCursor.InsertFeature pfeatureBuffer
pfeatureCursor.Flush
Set pFeat.Shape = pPoly

m_pAC.PartialRefresh esriViewGeography, Nothing, Nothing
```

Where am I going wrong? Also has anyone got any code examples with creating multiple buffers at various distances?

Answer (score 1):

Stupid mistake 
the line

```
Set pFeat.Shape = pPoly
```

should have been above

```
pfeatureCursor.InsertFeature pfeatureBuffer
pfeatureCursor.Flush
```